# Modify tags URL for current product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I've found this which lets me display a list of comma separated tags for the current product page...

```
echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span>' . _n( '', '', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );
```

...which will output like this:

```
<span>
    <a href="http://example.com/product-tag/name-1/" rel="tag">Name 1</a>,
    <a href="http://example.com/product-tag/name-2/" rel="tag">Name 2</a>
</span>
```

But what I actually want is to change the /product-tag/ part in the URL to something else, like this:

```
<span>
    <a href="http://example.com/something-else/name-1/" rel="tag">Name 1</a>,
    <a href="http://example.com/something-else/name-2/" rel="tag">Name 2</a
</span>
```

Any help would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on slightly modifiying the response from @snowflake, this works:

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag');
 foreach($terms as $term) {
   echo '<a href="'. $term->slug .'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need first to retrieve the terms :

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat');
```

then loop over the terms :

```
foreach($terms as $term) {
   echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
}
```

Instead of get_term_link you will have to construct your URL based on your rules.

Comment: Almost perfect thanks! Slight modification and now it's exactly how I need it:

`$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag');
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<a href="'. $term->slug .'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
 }`